# How can I write a function to lookup a url with parameters that has type safety?

Tags: typescript, next.js

I have a NextJS/React application.
We maintain a big object of internal urls, each of which defines a `createPath` function that looks something like this:

```
const URLS = {
    dashboard: {
        createPath: ({ accountNumber }: { accountNumber: string }) => `/account/${accountNumber}`
    },
    property: {
        createPath: ({ accountNumber, propertyId }: { accountNumber: string, propertyId: string }) => `/account/${accountNumber}/property/${propertyId}`
    }
}
```

so that when we link between pages, we do something like this:

```
<Link
  href={URLS.DASHBOARD.createPath({
  accountNumber: 'ABC123', // usually account number come out of the route params
 })}
>
 Go to account
</Link>
```

This works fine, but it means the structure of that URLS is used all over the project. In reality the object has lots of urls in it, and some nesting, and this makes it difficult to change without a lot of find-and-replacing.

Inspired mostly by the [django reverse utility](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse), I would like to be able to write something like:

```
getUrl('dashboard', { 'accountNumber': 'ABC123' })
```

which is not hard to do if write something like:

```
export const getUrl = (routeName: RouteNames, params: any): string =>
    URLS[routeName].createPath(params);
```

BUT what if I want type safety on the params?

I've had a go ([Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBASg9gV2BAcgQwLYQM5QLxQDkYATnJCaIVAD5EAma2AFgEZxon2EDcAUHwDGcAHbZgUAKowAMgGV8UAN58oaqIxbtO9AFzLV6o4JIQ0yAArnm+gBRKoaQcIQjgKBBlYQSUAL76Dk4ubh5ePvriJACWIgDm-gCU+AB8UAAGAPTBiG6ZACRKOa7unt4kfumGan4ANNVQpOQ+oIENxqbmEFbANlD2js65peEktY1kFKAAkvT+gYMhI+WRwDHx401TILOr6wl+yXhpWcV5hWfLPn6ZWy0gBUp3lDv0lQ1+fJ98AGaugsBoqIoHEIMBJCQADa2BpkJCoTAQfSETRsDhcQj1IxgTiYbBtIxGS5hFZQKKxOL8IyfRJ7Cn8X7-QHA0HgqEwoxw5DoLDI55ULHqHEkPEEwlqYllCJktb09pCyb3XYy-ZU9Q0unxBl-EQAoEiEFgiHQ2GIbmI-TweE8nCCtTC0WOEQgPi0lUUgycsEIEgG6TyADaXIRWAAugA6ExmSzWWwOjDYRL8b7CMRwSEQcOQuBxWys422FFMNE6TGe9SS0bIgCCACEAMIARgATABmTFfRKJPiZTITWLAXBQABE2SGJUydabbeHUCEomw6cz2dz+fZxEVLzLKiJ49CUpINYbLfbdomzReysIABEAKIAMQALABWABsHcO3d7-bcuFHl0nY821uTdQEyO8nzfWcBFTRcMyzHM8yNdd+RAbcGkrUlCCnE8O2xUCdmvZEIJfd96k-ARv2EEhTABKAABUFB8MhDygAB5VgACsIDoyFomQEVISgDA0BAKBREhMTsEgQRoh+MSAGsRDgAB3A1+WiW0oFYJAiFQ6Zr2oeg4BwKBlIkCAAA9onEKBYigUBICIII9yuVjyS1c9tmVDzKX8Qhwyga9ojmEBEGEswDWAOAoBUmJkD0gjZkIAB+Hs+1IAc-zHJZAOnVsQIvMDXHoCAfliCB6FnIA)) at doing this with overloading, so

```
type RouteNames = 'property' | 'dashboard';

const URLS = {
    dashboard: {
        createPath: ({ accountNumber }: { accountNumber: string }) => `/account/${accountNumber}`
    },
    property: {
        createPath: ({ accountNumber, propertyId }: { accountNumber: string, propertyId: string }) => `/account/${accountNumber}/property/${propertyId}`
    }
}

function getUrl(
    routeName: 'dashboard',
    params: {
        accountNumber: string;
    }
): string;

function getUrl(
    routeName: 'property',
    params: {
        accountNumber: string;
        propertyId: string;
    }
): string;

function getUrl(
    routeName: RouteNames,
    params: any
): string {
    return URLS[routeName].createPath(params);
}

console.log(getUrl('dashboard', {
    accountNumber: 'ABC123',
}))
// prints  "/account/ABC123" 
console.log(getUrl('property', {
    accountNumber: 'ABC123',
    propertyId: 'DEF456',
}))
// prints "/account/ABC123/property/DEF456" 

console.log(getUrl('property', {
    accountNumber: 'ABC123',
    propertyID: 'DEF456',
}))

// correct TS error: Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'propertyID' does not exist in type '{ accountNumber: string; propertyId: string; }'. Did you mean to write 'propertyId'?
// prints "/account/ABC123/property/undefined"
```

That works quite nicely, but it means I've got three different structures to add to when I create a new url - `RouteNames`, `URLS` *and* getUrl. Does anyone have any suggestions for a better implementation of this? I've had a good look through the [NextJS docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/linking-and-navigating) to see if I'm just missing a library utility for this and can't find one, and I also had a go at using a union type (of all the different parameter sets) in the `getUrl` signature for the params, but then each `createPath` would also have to use the union and the safety is watered down a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This approach might be promising. See Playground at https://tsplay.dev/NlXrRN

```
const URLS = {
    dashboard: {
        createPath: ({ accountNumber }: { accountNumber: string }) => `/account/${accountNumber}`
    },
    property: {
        createPath: ({ accountNumber, propertyId }: { accountNumber: string, propertyId: string }) => `/account/${accountNumber}/property/${propertyId}`
    }
} as const;

function getUrl<K extends keyof typeof URLS>(key:K, ...params: Parameters<typeof URLS[K]["createPath"]>){
    const createPath = URLS[key].createPath as (...args:unknown[]) => string;
    return createPath(...params)
}

console.log(getUrl('dashboard', {
    accountNumber: 'ABC123',
}))
// prints  "/account/ABC123" 
console.log(getUrl('property', {
    accountNumber: 'ABC123',
    propertyId: 'DEF456',
}))

// excess property
console.log(getUrl('dashboard', {
    accountNumber: 'ABC123',
    propertyId: 'DEF456',
}))

// misnamed property
console.log(getUrl('property', {
    accountNumber: 'ABC123',
    propertyID: 'DEF456',
}))

// correct TS error: Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'propertyID' does not exist in type '{ accountNumber: string; propertyId: string; }'. Did you mean to write 'propertyId'?
// prints "/account/ABC123/property/undefined"
```

Comment: As jsejcksn says, you should add `as const satisfies Record<string, {createPath: (...args:any[]) => string}>` to ensure that the const URLS lookup keeps the correct shape as people extend it.

Comment: Thanks for this, seems like this cast is a more specific way than jsescksn's answer for getting around the union issue I came up against, so I'll combine the two and see how that goes

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [const assertion (`as const`)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) constrained by a type that represents the schema of your expected `URLS` object (using the [`satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator)) to instruct the compiler to infer the type of the object using literal inference. (This also provides the benefit of preventing mutations to it later in your program.)

Then, you can derive a type `RouteName` which represents the keys of the `URLS` object — and a type utility `RouteParams` which will [index](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) the parameter type of the associated route's `createPath` function (using the [`Parameters<Type>` utility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype)).

These types can be used to create a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `getUrl` function which will help you reach your objective: to derive types in a way that future changes are made more maintainable by only requiring modification to the initial data structure. Below is an example:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBAqgJQDIGUYF4YG8BQMYAmAhhABYBGIRATgQFzZ74zDUCmRUbACp6QwAosMIsFABXMFABy4gLbk21GAF8Gw0RKmyFShtGoBLMAHNVASgwA+JsxgADAPSaQkqI4AkWF252LqKvYANEwqIfgADtQgEUpQAJ7qtizsnDx8gsn4GmKu2vL+QTBRMXHxAJIEqkl2dj75utT6UEamANxZzCWx1AmVza0mHbWq4cyW6FYOzrlunt6zDf4qjt1l82u9FQSBY2E4KiIQLODQMBCchhAAZoZsxwhsoLQAPAbGJkXCrBxcvFD8GACABuRAANuI2AwiGB4hMpu9TKorB0cAlYjAEK4uNIiHI2BgYABrNjxEDXGDotjk+DIFCoqmY7Hpah4iAvBAwNgADy4YAID2ZuPxU0wvFZ+K41HZTCpNMQqAA2ggALqKgBEPzS-1I6pVOCsioADCrUddJMAoIZwDATGwoHBqGCOVzeWx+YLxDi8WwrAImNEvWxhVDMWMIjQ2QwsUHxWyOVYQuYBh9GPhHI4YAABKAQAC0PNiloL1Gi1AD9vE1DAtKVge9+JVADotX8+AIIxKIOYOiocDhQJAQGC2E2wSATAI7Q6nQJ1cQyJQaAR1V8mPUZAU9DB1QBBABCAGEAIwAJgAzKuDuYe-3BxBh6Px5Pp46wXPNglV2mRItN40GD3I8z0vcNoh6Pp6B3AARABRAAxAAWABWAA2K8VBvVF70fMcJyne03w-cCym-XB8A3PxtyAk8LyvSISK2cpoMAuCkLQ78MxgWDSxActMNvIA)

```ts
const URLS = {
  dashboard: {
    createPath: ({ accountNumber }: { accountNumber: string }) =>
      `/account/${accountNumber}`,
  },
  property: {
    createPath: (
      { accountNumber, propertyId }: {
        accountNumber: string;
        propertyId: string;
      },
    ) => `/account/${accountNumber}/property/${propertyId}`,
  },
} as const satisfies Record<string, { createPath: (value: any) => string }>;

type RouteName = keyof typeof URLS;

type RouteParams<R extends RouteName> = Parameters<
  typeof URLS[R]["createPath"]
>[0];

function getUrl<R extends RouteName>(
  routeName: R,
  params: RouteParams<R>,
): string {
  // @ts-expect-error
  return URLS[routeName].createPath(params);
}

console.log(getUrl("dashboard", {
  accountNumber: "ABC123",
}));

console.log(getUrl("property", {
  accountNumber: "ABC123",
  propertyId: "DEF456",
}));

console.log(getUrl("property", {
  accountNumber: "ABC123",
  propertyID: "DEF456", /* Error
  ~~~~~~~~~~
  Argument of type '{ accountNumber: string; propertyID: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ accountNumber: string; propertyId: string; }'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'propertyID' does not exist in type '{ accountNumber: string; propertyId: string; }'. Did you mean to write 'propertyId'? (2345) */
}));
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I'm having a play around with it. It's got a similar issue to the union type (of all the different parameter sets) that I mentioned, in that you need to use `@ts-expect-error` to get around this error
```
Argument of type '{ accountNumber: string; } | { accountNumber: string; propertyId: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ accountNumber: string; propertyId: string; }'. Property 'propertyId' is missing in type '{ accountNumber: string; }' but required in type '{ accountNumber: string; propertyId: string; }'.(2345) ...```

But some useful thoughts here!

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77469093/how-can-i-write-a-function-to-lookup-a-url-with-parameters-that-has-type-safety/77469284?noredirect=1#comment136574707_77469284) @GillyAmes That's just a TS limitation — not really a safety issue with the code. I just chose readability over a useless assertion like [`return (URLS[routeName].createPath as (_: typeof params) => string)(params);`](https://tsplay.dev/Wo1rPN). See this GitHub issue for more info: [microsoft/TypeScript#30581 — Wishlist: support for correlated union types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581)

Comment: Thanks for that link - I agree that this seems like a limitation of Typescript. Personally I'd suggest an assert like that means you're suppressing errors related to the limitation, whereas // @ts-expect-error would suppress other genuine type errors if someone changed that line. I think your solution is a good option, but I'm not sure if I'd call it type safe, so I'm wondering if the actual answer is 'no this is a limitation in Typescript, you can't write this in a type safe way'